# Ansible regex_replace- ho to extract specific value

Tags: regex, ansible

How I can extract this value from hostname with regex_replace like this.

I have regex_replace

```
"{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^\\D+|\\..*', '') }}"
```

And hostname like this

```
nginx09-2.domain.com
```

And I want extract only number after - (2), but my regex_replace extracing 09-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your pattern a bit to match the first number and `-`

```py
"{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^\\D+\\d+-|\\..*', '') }}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFkEbS/1)

**Details**

- `^\D+\d+-` - a start of string (`^`), then one or more chars other than a digit (`\D+`), then one or more digits (`\d+`) and a `-` char
- `|` - or
- `\..*` - a dot (`\.`) and then the rest of the string (`.*`).

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the number and replace the string with it:

```
"{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('^.*-(\\d+).*$', '\\1') }}"
```

---

```sh
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 'nginx09-2.domain.com' | regex_replace('^.*-(\\d+).*$', '\\1') }}"

# 2
```